# A Step Involving the Binomial Theorem: Can You Explain Why its Valid?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I have been given a step in an evaluation of an integral, but I can't work out what theorem has been used:

See:

$=\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^n\left((b+c)\cos x-\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2n}}{n!}dx$

$=\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_{2m}^{2n}a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m}\cos^{2n-2m}x\left(\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2m}}{n!}dx-\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_{2m-1}^{2n}a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m+1}\cos^{2n-2m+1}x\left(\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2m-1}}{n!}dx$

Certainly the binomial theorem has been used, but why are the two terms valid?

There must be a trick used but I can't work it out...

-Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They've just separated even and odd terms.  Notice the following:

$$(x-y)^{2n}=\sum_{m=0}^{2n}(-1)^{m}\binom{2n}{m}x^{2n-m}y^m=\\\underbrace{\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{2n}{2m}x^{2n-2m}y^{2m}}_{\text{even terms}}-\underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{2n}{2m-1}x^{2n-2m+1}y^{2m-1}}_{\text{odd terms}}$$

Comment: Ok thanks for this. Sorry about the simplicity.

Comment: @AlexanderGiles: No worries.  Notice that I simplified your expression significantly by replacing your large expressions with a single variable.  It makes seeing the math a lot easier.  Perhaps the reason you couldn't see the trick is due to the large expression with which you were working.